# Avoid content to push up content above it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the search bar stay in the center of the screen but this is what happens when content is added below it:

[image: My design now]

As you can see in the image the text is pushing up the search bar but I want the search bar to stay always in the center of the screen and all the text to go below it.
I'm using flexbox by the way. Here's how my code looks like:

```css
/* GENERAL STYLES */

* {
  outline: none !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4c4c4c;
}

body,
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Wikipedia Viewer heading */

.title {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* SEARCH BAR */

.fa {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.form-search {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-basis: 1000px;
}

.form-search input {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  border-right: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* Styles for input placeholder with support for different browsers */

.form-search input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #a5a5a5;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.form-search input::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #a5a5a5;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.form-search input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #a5a5a5;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.form-search input::-o-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #a5a5a5;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  background: #EE3524;
  color: #FFF;
  flex-basis: 300px
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #cf2010;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Styles for "tell me what to read" text */

.main-container>a {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

.main-container>a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #EE3524;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.main-container>a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.main-container h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="javascript/script.js" async></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="images/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
    <title>Wikipedia Viewer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main-container">
        <h1 class="title">Wikipedia Viewer</h1>
        <form>
          <div class="form-section form-search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search here...">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">
            <i class="fa fa-search aria-hidden=true"></i>
          </button>
        </form>
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank">
          <h2>Tell me what to read</h2>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="search-results-container">
        <h1 id="description"></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code see your `.wrapper {` - should be clear that any additional content you throw inside it - will reflect to the position of the desired three elements (title, search and link) - pushing them upwards.

instead, if the cumulative height of your three elements will not alter you could:

```
padding-top: calc(50vh - <half form height px>);
```

like i.e:

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 60%;
}

#aboveTheFold{
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#searchForm {
  padding-top: calc(50vh - 40px); /* minus half form height */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="aboveTheFold">

  <form id="searchForm">
    <h1>WIKIPEDIA VIEWER</h1>
    <input name="search" tyle="text"><input type="submit" value="VIEW">
    <p><a href="#">Tell me what to read</a></p>
  </form>

  <p style="height:200vh;border:4px dashed blue;">Lorem ipsum longis textis...</p>
</div>
```